# What file to update in an XCode project when some folders names are updated?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have changed the name of two folders of an XCode project and when I open this project, it doesn't work anymore (XCode can't find the files where the name of the folders were changed). I know it's a little issue and I have tried to find where to update the references to these particular folders in XCode but couldn't find how to.

[image]

*I have changed where it is written "NewName"*

Can you help me to solve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Blue Folders in Xcode are physical folders on disk in the project folder.
Navigate to the project folder in Finder by right-clicking on a valid item in the side bar > Show in Finder, quit Xcode, rename the folders in Finder accordingly and reopen the project.

Then check the Build Settings of the target if there are any path references using the old folder names and change them, too.